# SSIS Permissions issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How can we set permissions for users to only allow them to download  SSIS packages from the production server and but deny them permissions to run any package in the Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053(SQL.90).aspx

If i assign users to any of the DB roles db_dtsadmin, db_dtsltduser, and db_dtsoperator they will automatically have permission to run the package.

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "download SSIS packages from the production server"?  If you mean for development, I would think that you would use a source  control system to store your packages for development, and limit production access to your DBA/operator staff.  Developers should not need access to the Production server (beyond maybe read-only to the data for troubleshooting production issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default database roles mentioned in the question allows users to run the package. The work around is to create new role in MSDB and assign the users privileages to execute the stored procedure "sp_dts_getpackage".